# C# How to make this HttpRequest Async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have this code:

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
using (WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I want on the finish this request, run this code:

```
MessageBox.Show("Finish");
```

Also, when i run this code, my program become freeze. I think this problem solve with async HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

In order to "**There are many different ways**" that stated in original answer, its better to consider using async/await pattern that is done by **Eser in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32530252/3110834) which is better answer**

When there is async method like `GetResponseAsync` to do such job, its better to use it and avoid creating task.

Consider reading great posts of Stephen Cleary:

- [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)
- [UI Guidelines for Async](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/ui-guidelines-for-async.html)
- [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

---

**ORIGINAL**

There are many different ways, for example:

```
string url= "http://www.google.com";
string result = "";
Task.Run(() =>
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    using (WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}).ContinueWith(x =>
{
    //MessageBox.Show(result);
    MessageBox.Show("Finished");

    //here you can not easily set properties of form 
    //you should use Invoke pattern

});
```

This way the application will be completely responsive while the task is executing and there is no freezing anymore.

Comment: I'll repeat one of my deleted comments.. You are creating an unnecessary task just not the block UI. but there are already async methods available as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: @Eser you are right, but this way the user may need minimum changes while he can refer to your answer ans I mentioned in edit :)

Answer (score 14):

You can do it like (in an *async* method):

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
using (WebResponse myResponse = await myRequest.GetResponseAsync())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("Finish");
```

But I would recommend to use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var result = await client.GetStringAsync(URL);
}
MessageBox.Show("Finish");
```

BTW: By using `GetStringAsync` you use the encoding your site is using which may not be `UTF8`

Comment: @Downvoter would you care to share your reason.... It is not blocking the UI, it doesn't create an extra Task as in accepted answer. It will not have a synchronization problem if this method wants to **return** `result`.  What am I missing?

Comment: It seems down voters attacked this post, specially my answer:)

Comment: @RezaAghaei It is not the same. I would never use your answer with .Net >= 4.5

Comment: Personal preferences are respected :) I'll be happy if you share dark side of the answer :) you can take a look at [Task.ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: My personal preference is async/await pattern, also, But IMO the answer I provided for the question is a good fit.

Comment: Specially considering that I've mentioned "There are many different ways"

Comment: SO is not a place for fight:)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes you are right, but when I see downvotes on a correct answer which can be easily tested, I get angry,,, Maybe my understanding about SO is wrong.

Comment: I never down vote a good answer (like your answer) :) and I'll edit my answer to point async/await.

Comment: BTW: I don't see my comments about "why I wouldn't use his answer" . Who the hell removed that......Why?...

Comment: @EmpereurAiman I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Eser I mean if the answer is beneficial(In the best way) to both the OP and future readers, vote up.
Not just "You vote me, I vote you"

Comment: @EmpereurAiman I didn't downvote(or upvote) other answer. OK. use your personal rules in SO. But Sorry, I am not interested in your preferences....

Comment: This is not my "personal" preferences. I don't see anything wrong in what I said

Comment: @EmpereurAiman I edited the answer, hope you find it useful:)

Comment: @Eser I edited the answer, hope you find it useful:)

Comment: Let's go and answer other questions

Comment: @Eser: Don't pay attention to the drive-by downloaders. It happens (and no doubt more often than it should), but just let it roll off you. +1, BTW.

Comment: @Eser I edited the post again to don't mislead users in future. +1 to your answer, hope it makes you more happy and keeps bad feelings completely away.

Comment: @StephenCleary I edited the post to don't mislead users in future and guided them yo read your great posts about Asynchronous Programming

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient in System.Net.Http for this(Assuming .net > 4.5):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var code = client.GetAsync(URL).ContinueWith(x =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("finish");
    client.Dispose();
});
```

You should add some error checking in continue with to be sure.